# Assignment operator explanation in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Conversions {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                    int index = 3;
                    int[] arr = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40};

                    arr[index] = index = 2; //(1)
                    System.out.println("" + arr[3] + " " + arr[2]);

            }
    }
```

I have this and it gives:

```
2 30
```

I was hoping it will give

```
40 2
```

At (1) Why was the value of the index in assignment not changed to 2 ( and kept as 3). ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [right-associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators) of `=` implied by [section 15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) of the Java Language Specification (JLS) means that your expression can be represented as a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), thus:

```
           =
    +------+-------+
    |              |
arr[index]         =
              +----+----+
              |         |
            index       2
```

But then, [section 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) states:

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

Therefore, `arr[index]` is evaluated *before* `index = 2` is, i.e. *before* the value of `index` is updated.

---

Obviously, you should never write code that relies on this fact, as it relies on rules that almost no reader understands.

Comment: Nitpick: `arr[index]` is not evaluated as it's not even expression here. `arr` and `index` are.

Comment: @zch: `arr[index]` is an expression, no?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, not really on the left side of assignment (in Java). It surely doesn't work like an expression there.

Comment: @zch: Hmm, sort of.  But indeed the quote in your answer describes it as an expression...

Comment: In other words, never be ashamed to use parentheses.

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't think parentheses could help the OP get the answer they were expecting...

Comment: I went too far calling it not-an-expression, my point was that it's never evaluated as an expression (as in 15.13.1). Sorry for pointless discussion.

Answer (score 5):

> [Java language Specification: 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) =
>
> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.13),
>   possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> - First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array
>     access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and
>     no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the **index subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason and the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no
>     assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the **right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes
>     abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - [...] (further steps are explained)

As you can see the index is evaluated before the right-hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

1. The array index header is evaluated first, to conclude the appropriate location for the assignment (`arr[index]`).
2. All following operators are evaluated for precedence, and found equal (all operators are assignments and thus have the same precedence).
3. Than the operands are evaluated according to the associativity, which is right-to-left for the assignment operator.